# Need help to make the pictures stand next to each column on the left

Tags: html, css

I've tried for hours to make the 1 picture stand next to a column (and the next one too, to the 2nd column) but I just can't get it to work right.. Can anyone help me with what I'm doing wrong?

http://jsfiddle.net/xp419wgc/

```css
.column2 {
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 100px;
}

.row2:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
  }
  
  .persons {
    font-family: dosis;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 200px;
    background: rgba(255, 200, 255, 0.8);
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    font-size: 14px;
    }
```

```html
<div class="persons"><br>
<div class="row2">
  <div class="column2">
    <h2>Jane Doe</h2><hr align="left" width="80%" noshade><p1>OFFICE</p1>
    <p>
<p>Mail: something@something.com
    <br>Phone: 123
</p>
    <br><br>

  </div>
    <img src="http://www.infoprobe.com.au/site/images/drblankfem.gif" height="10%" width="10%">
    <img src="http://www.infoprobe.com.au/site/images/drblankfem.gif" height="10%" width="10%">
  <div class="column2">
    <h2>Jane Doe</h2><hr align="left" width="80%" noshade><p1>OFFICE</p1>
    <p>
  <p>Mail: something@something.com
    <br>Phone: 123
</p>


</div></div>
```

Comment: Do you want the images next to the person name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your columns are floating, but your images are not. Meaning your columns will float together and your images will be displayed after.

I would suggest adding float: left to your images as well

Comment: YES! Thank you very much! Im still new to HTML & CSS and this works perfectly !

Answer (score 0):

Use css grid to avoid those problem.
 u can try it by making classes for those image like this

```
.class {
display: grid;
//and then grid your images where u want to };
```

that would be. Useful !